# Layout for table with 2 columns swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to display some data as a table with 2 columns - on the left side there must be portion and on the right - ingredients. I would like to have something similar to this picture below.

Which Ui elements could you advice me to use to get this kind of view?
[image: Example]

Comment: `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`, setting separator to `none`

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell` that has two fields, such as `amount` and `ingredient`. Constrain the `amount` to a fixed width.

Comment: is it possible to build table in other class and view? I have a screen, where the mentioned table is appearing by scrolling down

Comment: Sure. You put a `UITableView` component in the scroll view where you want it, then, make your view controller extend `UITableViewDataSource` (and `UITableViewDelegate`, if needed) and implement `numberOfSections(in:)`, `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`, and `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, just as you would in a `UITableViewController`. Just note that putting a table view in a scroll view can be tricky for auto layout, since you don't want the _table_ to scroll; you want the whole scroll view's contents to scroll.